# How much money can we make? v2

Tags: mathematics, strategy, optimization

This is follow up question to [How much money can we make?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61703/how-much-money-can-we-make)

---

> My five friends and I used to loan each other money all the time.  But
>   over the past several years we have moved apart.  We don't trust
>   PayPal, banks, or the postal service so transferring money over such
>   great distances is extremely difficult.
>
> Fortunately, we have discovered a set of 6 magical fax machines! 
>   While ordinary fax machines are unable to fax money, these magical fax
>   machines can*.  And like any fax machine, it is possible to retrieve
>   the documents you put into it (including money) even while the
>   receiving fax machine produces a copy.
>
> But these fax machines are not perfect.  Each machine can only send
>   one fax to each other machine (so 5 faxes per machine, for 30 faxes
>   total).  These faxes can be for any amount of money, but once a fax is
>   started it cannot be interrupted.
>
> For example, if I have \$30 and my friend has \$40, then I can fax my
>   money to my friend and then I will have \$30 and my friend will have
>   \$70.  If my friend fax me back, then I will have \$100 and he will
>   have \$70, and neither of us can fax any money to each other any more.
>
> Our years of traveling have left my 5 friends and I broke. Each of us
>   has exactly $1 and one special fax machine.
>
> Working together, what is the maximum amount of money that the six of
>   us can create?
>
> *and there won't be any problems with the fact that all your bills are copies of each other.  It's *magic*

---

This time you are trying to maximize your money instead of maximizing sum of the money and your friends are of course trying to help you.

> How much can you make at most?

**Note:** You may need to use computer programming or you may not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have nothing resembling a proof that this is optimal, but a bit of computer-searching found a sequence that appears to get

> \$55287 via the following sequence of transfers: (1, 0), (5, 1), (2, 5), (5, 2), (3, 5), (5, 3), (4, 5), (5, 4), (1, 5), (4, 1), (1, 4), (3, 1), (4, 3), (3, 4), (2, 3), (4, 2), (2, 4), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1), (2, 0), (0, 2), (3, 0), (0, 3), (4, 0), (0, 4), (5, 0), (0, 5).

Here's the crappy Python code I wrote to do it. It's doing simulated annealing. I made a guess at some parts of the solution by extrapolation from the (more-likely-optimal) solutions the same code found for smaller n, and forced it to look at only solutions fitting that pattern; I hope it's clear what to delete and change to undo that.

```
import math, random
n_people = 6
edges = []
for i in range(n_people): edges.extend((i,j) for j in range(n_people) if j != i)
# Ugly hack: enforce conjectured shape of solution
# (to not do this, remove next 3 non-comment lines and see
# single change below; note also that this needs changing if n_people
# changes)
edges0 = [(1,0), None, (2,1), (1,2), (0,1), (2,0), (0,2), (3,0), (0,3), (4,0), (0,4), (5,0), (0,5)] # adjust if n_people changes
edges1 = [e for e in edges if e not in edges0]
edges = edges0[:1] + edges1 + edges0[2:]
n_edges = len(edges)
def score(edges):
    money = n_people*[1]
    for (i,j) in edges:
        money[i] += money[j]
    #return sum(money) # use this to optimize total money (older problem)
    return money[0] # use this to optimize your own money (newer problem)
def mutate(edges):
    edges = edges[:]
    # The -11 version is for the "restricted" optimization
    #i,j = random.sample(range(n_edges),2)
    i,j = random.sample(range(1, n_edges-11),2)
    edges[i],edges[j] = edges[j],edges[i]
    return edges
curr = score(edges)
best = (curr, edges)
print(best)
temp = 8000
while True:
    candidate = mutate(edges)
    cscore = score(candidate)
    if cscore > curr or random.random() < math.exp((cscore-curr)/temp):
        edges = candidate
        curr = cscore
        if curr > best[0]:
            best = (curr, edges)
            print("new best", curr, edges)
    temp = 0.999993 * temp
    if temp < 1:
        print("resetting", curr, edges)
        temp = 8000
```

Comment: If using a code solution, it would be really great if you could post the code in the answer so future readers can compare their version against yours.

Comment: Yeah, will do at some point.

Comment: this is what I have found as well after your last edit. I am pretty sure (like 99% sure) there is no better answer. Thanks @GarethMcCaughan. I will wait a little then accept your answer. Was it just pure brute force or did you apply something else?

Comment: Fairly brutish -- simulated annealing -- except that after a while I looked at the shape of the best solutions it had found for n=2,3,4,5, made a guess at some features the best solution for n=6 was likely to have, and sped things up by restricting the search accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is optimal but I think you can get

> $\$39,812$

Strategy

> First, have you (numbered $0$) and four other friends to build up the maximum amount of money between yourselves using the strategy from the answer to the [previous question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61743/18422). 
>  Specifically, if your friends are numbered $1$ to $4$ then the sequence of moves is 
>  $(0,1) - (1,2) - (2,1) - (1,3) - (3,1) - (1,0) - (0,3) - (3,0) - (0,2) - (2,3) - (3,2) - (2,0) - (0,4) - (4,2) - (2,4) - (4,3) - (3,4) - (4,1) - (1,4) - (4,0)$ 
>  If I've gotten my numbers right, this gives the following monetary distribution among you and your friends: 
>  $0: \$1485, 1: \$690, 2: \$199, 3: \$365, 4: \$1369 $ 
>  Then, with the other friend numbered $5$, proceed with the following sequence of moves: 
>  $ (0,5) - (5,4) - (4,5) - (5,1) - (1,5) - (5,3) - (3,5) - (5,2) - (2,5) - (5,0) $ 
>  This exploits the idea of copying the largest amount of money each step. You should end up with $ \$ 39,812$ 
>  Feel free to correct me here, I rushed this so may have made mistakes.